# How to implement geofencing code for apple map ios 9

Tags: ios, location, geofencing

I have two locations one is the driver and other is the rider.I have lat n long available for both.I want to hit an api when the driver enters in the geofence area of the riders location.

i went through QKGeofenceManager demo project:
using this i can provide lat n long and the radius to find geofence.

But the issue is do i have to update driver location every time in background and what condition should be applied so the the callback is made when the driver enters the geofence area of rider.If the ap is in background how will it handle everything.
Do i have to make any changes in appdelegate

```
- (NSArray *)geofencesForGeofenceManager:(QKGeofenceManager *)geofenceManager
{
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
    NSMutableArray *geofences = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[fetchedObjects count]];
    for (NSManagedObject *object in fetchedObjects) {
        NSString *identifier = [object valueForKey:@"identifier"];
        CLLocationDegrees lat = [[object valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        CLLocationDegrees lon = [[object valueForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue];
        CLLocationDistance radius = [[object valueForKey:@"radius"] doubleValue];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon);
        CLCircularRegion *geofence = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:center radius:radius identifier:identifier];
        [geofences addObject:geofence];
    }
    return geofences;
}
```

Comment: If you have set up the geofence region to be monitored then you will get a call to your `didEnterRegion` delegate callback, even if your app is in the background

Comment: @Paulw11 where do u have to call these methods,In appdelegate or in the class where i have the locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative to achieve this task.
As my delegate method of Didenterlocation was not called,i applied another approach.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager

     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    // If it's a relatively recent event, turn off updates to save power
    NSLog(@"%@ locations",locations);

    float Lat = _locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    float Long = _locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;

    NSLog(@"Lat : %f  Long : %f",Lat,Long);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(28.58171,77.2915457);

    NSLog(@"center check %@",center);
    CLCircularRegion *region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:center
                                                                 radius:500
                                                             identifier:@"new region"];
    BOOL doesItContainMyPoint = [region containsCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Lat,Long)];

    NSLog(@"success %hhd", doesItContainMyPoint);

}
```

by keeping track of the current location,whenever the current location coordinates enter into the coordinates of the center region,you can fire a notification that the user has entered this particular region.